# Edit "save file" manager in Xubuntu 22.04?

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, appearance

I recently upgraded to 22.04 and I want to change the name of the box/manager/whatever you call it, that pops up when you are saving a file. Preferably I would like to put the "Save" button back down at the bottom and have some maximize/minimize buttons. Is there any way to go about doing this, or to change this program to another one that looks more normal?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does looks more normal mean?

Comment: It certainly is possible, thanks to the system being open source software!